# Qual a utilidade do ViewState?

Tags: c#

Em uma aplicação em que comecei a dar manutenção, há varias menções no código. E por isso gostaria de saber o que é e também para o que serve e ficar mais por dentro do que a aplicação faz.

Segue dois exemplos de como é utilizado:

```
List<domEstagioGrid> list = dao.ListaTodos(ViewState["WHERE"].ToString());


ViewState["COLIGADA"] = this.dgvLISTA.DataKeys[id]["CODCOLIGADA"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tem muito o que explicar. A [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.viewstate?view=netframework-4.8) da boas explicações sobre o `ViewState` e há [outros conteúdos](https://www.devmedia.com.br/conceitos-e-sintaxe-usando-viewstate/18095) com exemplos e explicações.

Basicamente ele armazena dados que poderão ser utilizados após um `PostBack`.

No seu caso ele armazena um valor chamado `ViewState["COLIGADA"]`, esse valor poderá ser utilizado na página após o `PostBack`. O outro que foi setado em algum outro momento (`ViewState["WHERE"]`) está sendo usado para enviar como parâmetro ao método `ListaTodos`.